# Detecting Ordinal plurals

Tags: dialogflow-es

How can I detect ordinal plurals in DialogFlow?

I know there is the sys.ordinal entity. But that will only detect.

Third Fourth

But I want to detect

Thirds Fourths

Answer (score 0):

Enter (be sure to actually press enter) your training phrase with an ordinal plural, for example, "I would like to cut the pie in fourths." Then highlight the word fourths and a dialogue box should pop up. Find @sys.ordinal:ordinal and click it. Do that with a couple of other plural ordinals for good measure and then it will recognize them all.

Note that sometimes the dialogue box fails to pop up when you highlight a word. If this happens just try highlighting it a couple more times. Usually it will work eventually.